# The result of sizeof(pointer variable )/sizeof(first element of array ) always shows 2

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

Normally to find the size of the array, we do..

```
int A[]={1,2,67,9,0,-1,-90};
int n=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
printf("the size of the array is %d\n", n);`
```

The output of the above code shows size as 7.
But when A is put into some pointer and then, if we try to do the same, it shows

```
int A[]={1,2,67,9,0,-1,-90};
int *B=A;
int n=sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]);
printf("the size of the array is %d\n", n);
```

the answer is 2

How do I find the size of the array using this pointer.

Comment: I'm assuming you're on a 64bit O/S and machine.... If so, the pointer is (probably) 8 bytes, the int is 4 bytes. 8/4 == 2. If you looked at the size of the thing that the pointer is pointing to you may have more luck!

Comment: See also [Is an array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/1015722)

Comment: It comes into mind there might be a reason a **pointer** is not called "array". Maybe because **a pointer is not an array**?

Comment: > How do I find the size of the array using this pointer.

No - not possible.

Answer (score 5):

> int n=sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]);

The result is 2 because `sizeof(B)` is `sizeof( pointer )` NOT `sizeof( array )`

```
int A[]={1,2,67,9,0,-1,-90};
int *B=A;    // <-- B is a pointer pointing to the first element of array A
int n=sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]);    // <-- sizeof(pointer) / sizeof(int)
```

The result is machine-dependent, but you can verify that the output of these two `printf`s are the same:

```
printf( "sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]) = %zu\n", sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]) );
printf( "sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int) = %zu\n", sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int));
```